# Function to add an image in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a function in Tkinter that imports an image. But the function seems to execute but I am not able to access the image object. why did the problem occur?

```
import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Guess Geek")
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.resizable(0, 0)

def importimg(x,y):
    x=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=y)

importimg('bgimg','main1.jpg')
bg = Label(root, image=bgimg, )
bg.place()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think I understand, could you explain further what the problem is?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: this is not the way to properly open an image in tkinter mayb [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loading-images-in-tkinter-using-pil/) can solve your problem

Comment: it is actually working well without the function. I wanted to put it inside function so that I could reduce the number of lines

Comment: I have given you the solution. You should try making an image gallery with 'Next' and 'Back' button for practice

Comment: This code would make a perfect base for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I know that you have already accepted an answer but I want to show you my take on your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import PIL.ImageTk
import PIL.Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Guess Geek")
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.resizable(0, 0)

def importimg(file_name):
    return PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(file_name))

bg_img = importimg('main1.jpg')
bg = ttk.Label(root, image=bg_img)
bg.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

So here's what I have changed in your code:

- Instead of bringing al of `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` in the global scope, I imported only the module
- I renamed `tkinter` as `tk` and `tkinter.ttk` as `ttk` for the convenience of having shorter names to use
- I imported the `PIL.ImageTk` module without bringing them in the global scope just to be sure of where it came from
- I imported the `PIL.Image` module without bringing them in the global scope because there is a `tkinter.Image` that would have overrode it if with kept both in the global scope (the way your code was written)
- [`PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) first argument should an PIL's image (provided easily by [`Image.open()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open)) and **not** just the file name
- `importimg()` returns the object created from the class `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()`. This will get assigned to `bg_img`
- Instead of using the `place()` geometry manager, I've used the `grid()`'s one. It's generally [recommended](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) by the TkDocs website

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the code is perfect.

1. The problem here is that the code is unable to assign the image to the variable `bgimg` and that is happening because in *line 15* you have defined `bgimg` as a string and not as a variable

Instead of

```
importimg('bgimg','main1.jpg')
```

Try

```
bgmain = 0
importimg(bgimg,'')
```

2. The Program might not be able to find the directory of image. I would recommend you to use `.open()` method to define image location. With this you can also specify the `Width` and `Height` of the image

*`.open()` method*

```
path = ".\imagename.jpg" or ".\images\imgname.jpg" or "F:\New folder\imgname.jpg"
k = Image.open(path)
k = k.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
bgimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(k)

LABEL = Label(bg="black", image=bgimg)
LABEL.place(height=300, width=300)
```

If you still can't figure out what the problem is just refer to the following

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Guess Geek")
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.resizable(0, 0)

def importimg(x,y):
    path = y
    k = Image.open(path)
    k = k.resize((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    x=ImageTk.PhotoImage(k)
    global bgimg
    bgimg = x

bgimg = 0
importimg(bgimg,".\foldername\imagename.jpg")
bg = Label(root, image=bgimg )
bg.place(width=400, height=400, relx=0.05, rely=0.1)
root.mainloop()
```